# Can I get the axis that will be returned by `pyplot.subplots` inside the constructor for the figure it creates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I'm using a custom figure class in a call to pyplot's `subplot()`

```
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(FigureClass=MyFigure)
```

and would like to use the axis object(s), `ax`, normally returned by `subplot()`, in the constructor to the custom figure class. For example, I'd like to take that axis and twin it:

```
class MyFigure(matplotlib.figure.Figure):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFigure, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.ax_one = self.method_that_gets_the_ax_returned_by_subplots()
        self.ax_two = self.ax_one.twinx()
        self.ax_three = self.ax_one.twinx()
```

but I can't find a way to get (what will be returned as) `ax` here. Using `gca()` results in a blank figure and an "extra" axis, for example; while using `get_axes()` results in errors (it's an empty list).

Is there a way to get the axis that will be returned by `subplots` inside the constructor for the figure it creates?

Comment: No because the axes do not exist at the time the `Figure` objects gets created.  I think you would be better putting that logic in the `add_subplot` function rather than the `__init__` function.  A figure does not have to have an axes and can have _any_ number of axes, hard-coding that sort of thing in the `__init__` does not seem like a great idea.

Comment: @tcaswell: is there a figure method that `pyplot.subplots` calls to create and add the axes it returns?

Comment: `add_subplot`  You should go read the source (it is in pyplot.py), it will clarify a lot of these questions.

Comment: @tcaswell: I see that `add_subplot` is responsible for creating the axis object that's returned by `pyplot.subplots`, but I need that axis to start with. Where does it come from; and can I even safely override `add_subplot` without all kinds of side effects (given that this figure class always has only the axes defined above)?